# Rearranging RGB values to GRB, GBR, BRG, BGR, and RBG through an entire directory

Tags: image, python-2.7, numpy, opencv, python

I have a directory of images for a CNN. I would like to be able to rearrange each band in a different order to help better train my model to allow it to recognize my objects. I so far have some code working with cv2. It is separating the bands, but I am having trouble rearranging the bands.

```
import cv2
import numpy

img = cv2.imread("IMG_4540.jpg")
g,b,r = cv2.split(img)
cv2.imwrite('green_channel.jpg', g)
```

I would like to have 6 separate images all with different band combinations from one singular image if possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can just form all reorderings with numpy's indexing capabilities.

```
import numpy as np 
from itertools import permutations
# first generate all sets of rearrangements you'd like to make.. 
orderings = [p for p in permutations(np.arange(3)) if p!=(0,1,2)]
# [(0, 2, 1), (1, 0, 2), (1, 2, 0), (2, 0, 1), (2, 1, 0)]
# rbg, brg, and so on. 

# then reorder along axis=-1 using these. (0,1,2) --> (0,2,1) and so on. 
for order in orderings:
    reordered = im[...,order]
    # then save each an appropriate filename 
    cv2.imsave('filename.jpg', reordered)
del reordered, order
```